# How to iterate convex hull over a list of point's clusters?

Tags: python, iteration, convex-hull

I have a dataframe with latitude and longitude values grouped by clusters (result of a dbscan clustering method) In total I have 150 clusters. (extract of th first line) :

```
    Latitude    Longitude   cluster-db
2   35.793020   -110.388760     90
32  32.842108   -193.565837     60
33  36.800923   -110.566971     4
34  31.896220   -99.551749     147
```

For each of these clusters I would like to obtain the coordinates (from convex hull) of the points that form the perimeter : [image: example cluster 0]

I would like to obtain a dataframe containing cluster number (150 row) and the associates vertices points coordinates.

for example cluster 1 has 3 perimeter points :

```
cluster    Perimeter 
1          35.793020   -110.388760, 32.842108   -193.565837, 36.800923   -110.566971
```

I've tried this code, and hull seems to give a result for only one cluster (indeed, the first one : cluster 0)

```
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

z=[] #HULL simplices coordinates will be appended here

for i in range (0,num_clusters-1):
    dfq=data_conv[data_conv['cluster-db']==i]
    Y = np.array(dfq[['Latitude', 'Longitude']])
    hull = ConvexHull(Y)
    plt.plot(Y[:, 1],Y[:, 0],  'o')
    z.append(Y[hull.vertices,:].tolist())
    for simplex in hull.simplices:
        ploted=plt.plot( Y[simplex, 1], Y[simplex, 0],'k-',c='m')

z

[[34.79267702, -109.3900481],
 [35.78415582, -101.39016576],
 [34.7959, -104.3892],
 [37.792889, -104.38547],
 [38.79321, -110.388667],
 [31.79231003, -103.38955313]]
```

How can I iterate this to all my clusters and save the result in the desired format  ?